# How do I select an element on a popup in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Yes (Enter)")
```

Doesn't seem to be able to locate the element. Figure I have to focus on the popup first but how?

[image: the button]

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of the page source? _Figure I have to focus on the popup first but how?_ Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> driver.find_element_by_link_text("Yes (Enter)")
> ```

First, this won't work because there is no button with that text anywhere. Secondly, the popup in this case occurs in an iframe.

First, you'll need to locate the iframe and switch to it.

```py
frame = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')  # may need to adjust to find the _correct_ iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Then you'll need to locate the appropriate element within that frame and perform those actions

```py
button = driver.find_element(by.FOO, ...)
button.click()
```

Then you'll probably want to switch back to the default context (get out of the iframe)

```py
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Lastly: don't try to use selenium to automate reddit; it's against the Terms of Service. There's an [API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/) that you should use instead.

Comment: Thanks! It's "Yes (Enter)" because it wasn't for reddit.